# What are my options for developing for Android?

Tags: android, libraries

I've finished setting up the Android SDK in Eclipse and now I have to wonder, what are some popular methods for developing a game on Android? My Java knowledge is pretty limited to be honest so I don't know much about the included graphics library or even if it works with Android, most of my experience is in C++ with Ogre or SFML. I understand SDL is pretty similar to SFML so I might give that a try. Also, should I use the newest version of the SDK (Android 4.0.3 API level 15 is what my AVD is) or an older version to support the most devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of methods to develop a game on Android. It depends on a specificity of the game you are going to create and your personal expirience.

In my projects I use *libgx* http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/. It's enough good to satisfy my expectations.

There are some cross-platform frameworks that make it possible to create games for Android and iOS (CoronaSDK, Marmalade).

I heard Ogre code is able to be compiled on Android. I think you should investigate this question :).

Please, let me know if it's possible.

What target version of SDK you should use you can see here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Best regards

Comment: I really like libgdx, thanks for recommending it. Also I looked into Ogre on Android, it's possible to get it working using a modified NDK from what I understand but it isn't ideal. I haven't tried since at the moment I don't need to do anything 3D related.

Answer (score 0):

Some links to help you further:

- [Getting started in Android game development](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/54-getting-started-android-game-development)
- [Playing with graphics in Android](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html)
- [The Game Loop](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/)
- [Writing real-time games for Android (Google I/O 2009)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic)

About the SDK - start off low, say Android 1.5. If you encounter things that are not available in this version, increase the build target. This way you can reach the most users.

Answer (score 0):

If I'd want to develope for Android as a starter, I'd:

1) Learn Java. It won't be tough if you're used to other languages like C++

2) Make some tutorials (Internet is full of them)

3) Develope for an older version of Android such as 2.2 or 2.3 (There's no need to develope for even older versions, as almost all cellphone's have been updated to at least 2.2). In my opinion, developing ***now*** for Ice Cream Sandwich is worthless as *nobody*  will be able to use your application (Ok there are some people, but they're not a lot actually). I think developing for 4.0 is atractive for big companies, with projects that can last for months, so when it's time for their app to be published, the market will be ready. Doing it before that is just closing your market  -I assume you're not going to enter with a giant application yet-

And that's kind of everything you should know :)